# simple angular checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have a T/F property called "valid" returning from an API call. I want to accurately display it as a checkbox, as well as allow the user to set/unset it. Setting or unsetting it will make a SAVE call.

```
{{vm.selectedQuestion}}
<md-checkbox
      aria-label="Confirmed"
      ng-model="vm.selectedQuestion.valid" 
      ng-click="vm.setReviewed()" 
      ng-checked="vm.selectedQuestion.valid">
       Valid
</md-checkbox>
```

.

```
        vm.setReviewed = function () {
            vm.selectedQuestion.valid = !vm.selectedQuestion.valid;
            // a bunch of other stuff
        };
```

If the question gets loaded with value: true, then I see the checked box. If I uncheck the box, **the valid property disappears from the object completely**.

I know I'm doing something wrong with the ng-model and the ng-checked, but I've tried every combination I can think of.

Astonishingly, the angular docs and examples do not seem to address this simple case as far as I have found.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply change it to:

```
{{vm.selectedQuestion}}
<md-checkbox
  aria-label="Confirmed"
  ng-model="vm.selectedQuestion.valid"
  ng-change="vm.setReviewed()">
   Valid
</md-checkbox>
```

with the function:

```
vm.setReviewed = function () {
    // a bunch of other stuff depending on the value of vm.selectedQuestion.valid
};
```

Usually there is no need to over-complicate it (unless there is something about `md-checkbox` that I am not aware of). There is also no need to manually toggle the value in the `ng-change` (it's already changed by `ng-model`, and the value of `vm.selectedQuestion.valid` you see in the function is already after the change).

Here is the link for the docs of `md-checkbox` directive with a clear example:
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdCheckbox

And the `ng-change` is as `ng-change` does, until angular goes v2, and then all bets are off. :)

**A few notes on directives in question (with input from OP comment):**

- `ng-click` happens *before* the change of the `ng-model` and the checkbox in the element
- `ng-change` happens *after* the change in the `ng-model` and the element
- `ng-checked` is used only to set the `checked` attribute of the element if it's evaluated to truthy - should not be used alongside `ng-model`

Comment: Simplifying it as you suggested made it easier to find the real problem. The ng-click event fires **before** the model is changed. So when setReviewed() is run, **vm.selectedQuestion.valid has not yet changed** - even though the checkbox shows it as changed.
I changed ng-click to ng-change and the problem has gone away. 
**Thank you.**

Comment: I always confuse the order of angular events - I remember for sure that ng-change is after the change, but forget that ng-click is before. ^^" Anyhow, glad to help! :)

Comment: Also, there are a few interesting nuggets in the docs of `ng-click`, `ng-change`, `ng-model`, `ng-checked`. Too bad these gotchas are buried deep there and not immediately apparent... Well, RTFM, nothing to do there. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following snippet

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="name" ng-model="name">{{name}}</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you